# Android navigation controller + dynamic fragment button action

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components

I am trying to implement a generic fragment to display a title, message and button action (here is the problem). I am not able to resolve the `executeAction()` method in a generic way. I have at least 20 screens, where the only difference is the title message and button action.

```
class InfoTemplateFragment : BaseFragment() {

    override fun getLayoutResId() = R.layout.fragment_template_info

    private val args: InfoTemplateFragmentArgs by navArgs()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        templateInfoTitleTextView.setText(args.title)
        templateInfoMessageTextView.setText(args.message)
        templateInfoButton.setText(args.buttonText)
        templateInfoButton.setOnClickListener {
            executeAction()  // How to make this dynamic?
        }
    }
}
```

**UI XML**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/templateInfoTitleTextView"
    style="@style/Heading1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin_super_extra_large"
    tools:text="Title"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/templateInfoMessageTextView"
    style="@style/BodyText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin_extra_large"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/templateInfoTitleTextView"
    tools:text="Message" />

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/templateInfoButton"
    style="@style/PrimaryOutlinedButtonRoundedCorner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

**The navigation graph is:**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/infoTemplateFragment"
    android:name="ui.templates.InfoTemplateFragment"
    android:label="InfoTemplateFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_template_info">
    <argument
        android:name="title"
        app:argType="reference" />
    <argument
        android:name="message"
        app:argType="reference" />
    <argument
        android:name="button_text"
        app:argType="reference" />
</fragment>
```

**To naviate to a new fragment I use:**

```
var bundle = bundleOf("title" to R.string.title_one,
"message" to R.string.message_one, "button_text" to R.string.accept)
view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.infoTemplateFragment, bundle)
```

[image]